# PcBSD 9: How to install PHP5

Tags: php, freebsd, bsd

I'm trying to install PHP5 on pcBSD9.  Inside my ports there is php5-session, php5-tidy, php52-session, and php52-tidy.  I'm guessing I'm to install either php5-tidy or php52-tidy but I don't know the differences.  There is no php5 directory.  Could someone explain the differences between 5 and 52 as well as session and tidy?  Thanks.

Comment: You need the root `php5` or `php52` module.  52 means version 5.2.

Comment: So do I need to update my ports?  If not, how do I obtain php5?

Comment: Actually, if you install any of those other php modules they should require php as a prerequisite so you could just try installing one - try `php52-session`, that sounds like a winner.

Comment: I'll try that.  Whats the difference between session and tidy?

Comment: I'm speaking from guesses here, but it seems that `tidy` probably has a minimal feature set while `session` includes session handling (I'm thinking in the same vein as "html-transitional" vs "html-frameset")

Comment: Oh, it turns out I lied. Tidy is a package: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: It says Tidy is depreciated and session exited with an error code 1.

Comment: I found out that php5 is in /usr/ports/lang/.  Now when I attempt to install I get this error "Can't cd to /usr/ports/lang/php5/work/php-5.3.8 no such directory"  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your ports tree is up-to-date, you should install the `/usr/ports/lang/php5` port. This will give you 5.3.10 currently, since php 5.2 is deprecated.

For updating the ports tree, I prefer `portsnap(8)`. It is in the base system of FreeBSD 9, which pcBSD9 is based on.